# Save indicator in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

There used to be an option in Notepad++ that when you save a file, it showed a green vertical bar on the left, and when you make any change, it turns yellow. This behavior is in Visual Studio and SQL Management Studio (example below).

How can I turn this feature on in Notepad++?

[image: SSMS 2012]

I know that the disk icon on the header, next to file name on the title bar, turns red for unsaved files and blue for saved ones (and grey for read-only files). But I'm looking for this feature so I can exactly know where the changes were made.

Thanks.

Comment: That's a function provided by a NP++ plugin -- not sure exactly which one though.  You must have had it installed previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one plugin called Change Markers. The plugin is located [here](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=71a486ea08eb407c&id=71A486EA08EB407C!129).  This has the green/yellow side-bar.

There is another plugin called Location Navigate. This plugin is located [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/locationnav/files/LocationNavigate_v0.4.7.7.zip/download)(Unicode) or [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/locationnav/files/LocationNavigateA_v0.4.7.7.zip/download)(ANSI).

Check the [plugin list](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/?title=Plugin_Central) for more options.

Comment: Change Marker isn't available through Plugins -> Plugin Manager -> Available?

Comment: Nope, that's why he was nice enough to give you a link. ;)

Comment: I installed Location Navigate. Had to play with a little bit. I selected "Mark with rect" and changed colors to match it with Visual Studio and SSMS. Thanks All.

Comment: This plugin is no longer available for 7.5.9. Can you please tell any alternative?